# Rings for which the product is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $\otimes=\otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ and let $\mu:R\otimes R\to R$ be the product map of $R$. I've been told that $\mu$ is an isomorphism if and only if $1\otimes x=x\otimes 1$ for every $x\in R$... this must be easy, but I can't see it!

$(\Rightarrow)$ is obvious, for both $1\otimes x$ and $x\otimes 1$ get mapped to the same thing, but I can't see the converse. I guess the inverse to $\mu$ must be the common map $R\to R\otimes R$ defined by $x\mapsto x\otimes 1=1\otimes x$, but... Why would the element $ab\otimes 1=1\otimes ab$ be equal to $a\otimes b$?

Comment: @JazzyMatrix: can't see why that would be true. The construction of $R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$ uses only the fact that $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so there's no *a priori* reason for it to interact nicely with the product in $R$.

Comment: Sorry -- I made a typo with the $r_i$s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $1 \otimes x = x \otimes 1$ for all $x \in R$. Let $a,b \in R$ be arbitrary, then we may compute
\begin{equation*}
 a \otimes b = (a \otimes 1) (1 \otimes b) = (1 \otimes a)(1 \otimes b) = 1 \otimes ab.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Indeed! Silly me, I didn't think to use the ring structure of $R\otimes R$.